# Howto access preferences created by onCreatePreferences() in another part of app?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I have a preferences screen which works great, using the code below it inflates the XML and saves / restores the preferences in the preference screen.

I am struggleing with two issues

(1) how to read these preferences from another part of my app, I think I need to set rootKey (which seems to be null at present) and getSharedPreferences() but am struggleing to make this work, any ideas ?

(2) possibly answered when the above is solved, howto init the preferences before I go to my preference screen when the app is run for the first time, in that state the preferences will not have been created by inflating the XML ?

Many thanks in advance from a newbe :)

```
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.preference.PreferenceFragmentCompat
import androidx.preference.PreferenceManager

class SettingsFragment : PreferenceFragmentCompat() {

    override fun onCreatePreferences(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, rootKey: String?) {
        setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.app_preferences, rootKey)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the `rootKey`, which is only for selecting which sub-screen of preferences you're currently showing.

By default, the preferences in PreferenceFragmentCompat are read and written to the default SharedPreferences. You can access these from anywhere in the app using `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)`.

If you want to use specific SharedPreferences on your settings screen, you can call this right before you call `setPreferencesFromResource()`:

```
preferenceManager.sharedPreferencesName = "mySpecificPreferences"
preferenceManager.sharedPreferencesMode = Context.MODE_PRIVATE
```

and then when you want a SharedPreferences instance elsewhere in the app you can use `context.getSharedPreferences("mySpecificPreferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)`.

I also recommend you call this at the entry point of your app, so all the defaults from the preferences are loaded before you start using preferences:

```
PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.preferences, true)
```

or

```
PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, "mySpecificPreferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, R.xml.preferences, true)
```

This loads the current defaults from your XML, so even if the user hasn't visited the settings screen yet, all the defaults will be in the SharedPreferences. Then when you call something like

```
sharedPreferences.getBoolean("someKey", true)
```

...that second argument for the default value to return when the preference is missing won't matter, because the preference won't be missing. Then you don't have to manage what your defaults are from all over the app.

"Entry point of your app" can be `onCreate()` of the first Activity that will be opened. But if there are multiple entry points, you probably want to subclass Application, put it in `onCreate()` of the Application, and set that application class in your manifest.